# Sorting References in nyt format with IEEEtranSN.bst

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, ieeetran

In my latex file, I have used natbib package with slight modification in IEEEtranSN.bst as bibliography-style. I use \cite{key} for Bhanot et al. (2015) and \citep{key} for (Bhanot et al., 2015) and getting references in the following format:

Bhanot, N., Rao, P. V., and Deshmukh, S. G., “Enablers and barriers of sustainable manufacturing: Results from a survey of researchers and industry professionals,” *Procedia CIRP*, Vol. 29 No. 1, pp. 562–567, 2015.

However, I wish to have them in the following format:

Bhanot, N., Rao, P. V. and Deshmukh, S. G. (2015), “Enablers and barriers of sustainable manufacturing: Results from a survey of researchers and industry professionals”, *Procedia CIRP*, Vol. 29 No. 1, pp. 562–7.

Can anyone please suggest any modification in IEEEtranSN.bst file or what code should be included in the preamble.

Comment: If you can provide a MWE, that would greatly increase your chances of getting an answer. Right now, it's hard to tell what bib file (for example) would produce the citation we're seeing.